# display error messages based on action

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have couple of messages to display in my search screen

**OnLoad of the screen**

```
<c:if test="${command.colour == null}">
        Please filter by colour
</c:if>
```

**If the search function, does not return any rows**

```
<c:if test="${fn:length(mainCommand.images)  lt 1}"> 
        No results Found 
</c:if>
```

At the moment, both of them are displayed for both the scenarios.
How can I disable/enable them depending on the scenario ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Can you elaborate and maybe tell us what the scenarios are?  Your code already chooses to show - or not show - each of them based on a condition.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was away few days to respond. Though both the conditions are different, they both are displayed when the page is launched. I want the first one to be displayed when the page is loaded and upon clicking on the search button and if it satisfies the second condition then second one should be displayed. I do not want the first one to be displayed in 2nd condition and second one to be displayed when page is launched.